# Do something when variable is not undefined

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a function (e.g. `getContent();`) in a script written in JavaScript that gets the XML content from a page, converts it to JSON and stores it in a variable (e.g. `var resultsJSON;`). This process takes 0.07 seconds to do, but it is still not fast enough for the rest of the script. The script then is supposed to use a portion of the JSON. When I test it, the console says that the variable `resultsJSON` is undefined. I put a `console.log` in the function to see when it actually gets the XML and stores it in the variable. It looks like the code is sent to get the content, and then the script continues running the next line of code after that before the content is added to the variable.

I would think that the issue has to do with the code being synchronous versus asynchronous. I have tried to learn about that, but I am having some trouble understanding it, partly due to me being new at JavaScript. How would I make the script wait for the variable to not be undefined before continuing with the rest of the script? Here is an example of what my script looks like:

```
var resultsJSON;
getContent();//gets XML from page, converts XML to JSON, makes resultsJSON = JSON
var item=resultsJSON.Item[0];
console.log(item);
```

The last two lines need to wait before being executed until resultsJSON has a value. How would I do this?

Just to let you know, I am able to use JQuery, but would prefer not to unless I absolutely have to.

Here is what the getContent function looks like:

```
function getContent() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            resultsJSON = xml2json.fromStr(this.responseText);
            console.log(resultsJSON);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", 'getResults.php?'+queryURL, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

I removed the variables defined inside of the function since they are irrelevant to the issue. The queryURL variable is one of these variables. This function uses a script called xml2json from [here](http://coursesweb.net/javascript/convert-xml-json-javascript_s2); the xml2json is defined in that script.

Comment: Without diving into async/await or promises ... in getContent(), after the content is retrieved, call a function that continues your code.  Can you provide the code for getContent() (just the relevant bits about getting the data and what it does with it afterwards)

Comment: @Doug being somewhat new at JavaScript, I don't know how to use callbacks. getContent is used in numerous cases, depending on what is needed. The actual script is much more complicated. I guess I could allow for an place to add a function. I am just not sure how to do it

Comment: it would be nice if there was function like when(var !== null){...} I know there is a when function in JQuery, but I was having issues with it working.

Comment: you can test if the variable is undefined -- but that could snowball into a lot of chaos ... `if(resultsJSON)` or something similar (if undefined it will return false and skip whatever comes after in its closure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick demo of a callback and how you may be able to apply it to your problem.  Essentially, you send your getContent() function the name of another function -- and then once getContent() resolves, you can then trigger the next function to continue on with your code:

```js
var resultsJSON = {};

getContent( printResult );
//           ^Pass in the function name that you want
// to get executed after getContent() resovles

function getContent( callback ){
//                   ^ 'callback' is just a variable
// name at this point. This variable refers to the function
// passed in, to be called back later

// a timeout to mimic something that takes some time, in this
// case 3 seconds
  setTimeout( function(){
    resultsJSON.Item = [];
    resultsJSON.Item[0] = 'apple';
    callback();
    // ^invoke the callback function, in this case, it's calling
    // printResult();
  }, 3000 );
}

function printResult(){
  console.log(resultsJSON);
}
```

Comment: Using the callback with the setTimeout resulted in an error, likely related to it timing out. Without the setTimeout, but with a callback produces the results I was wanting

Comment: Glad to hear :) Yeah, the setTimeout was included just to illustrate code taking time to process (like grabbing data or whatnot) -- it does not need to exist for a callback to work

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't really appear to be a synchronous vs. asynchronous problem, but rather a basic understand of what JS does problem.

```
var resultsJSON;
getContent();//gets XML from page, converts XML to JSON, makes resultsJSON = JSON
var item=resultsJSON.Item[0];
console.log(item);
```

In your code above, the function `getContent();` will execute immediately and then the JS engine will go to the next line where you're trying to read the response. However, the call to get the xml page likely hasn't completed yet. You should  make `getContent();` return your value rather than set a variable that is already declared. Inside of `getContent();` only return the value after the call has completed.

```
var resultsJSON = getContent();//gets XML from page, converts XML to JSON, makes resultsJSON = JSON
var item = resultsJSON.Item[0];
console.log(item);
```

Comment: *gets XML from page*: I think it is exactly a problem of making asynchronous callbacks . You should offer a solution with callback, not a return value.

Comment: What's wrong with making `getContet()` handle getting all of the data (including waiting for the asynchronous call to finish) and returning a value? In my opinion, it seems like bad practice to have a function set a value on an outside variable rather than return a  value.

Comment: @ChristianSirolli Can you post the inside of `getContent();` that would help the most in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: @mituw16 See the question now, I added a simplified version of it that still has the same basic features